# why to use 'iterator' to loop thru an ArrayList. It can be done without Iterator also right?

Tags: java, arraylist

why use 'iterator' to loop thru an ArrayList. It can be done without Iterator also right?
so the benefits of using iterator to loop thru an ArrayList

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

 public class IteratorDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Make a collection
    ArrayList<String> cars = new ArrayList<String>();
    cars.add("Volvo");
    cars.add("BMW");
    cars.add("Ford");
    cars.add("Mazda");

    // Get the iterator
    //Iterator<String> it = cars.iterator();

    // Looping without Iterator
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
        //System.out.println(it.next());

        System.out.println(cars.get(i));
    }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you just don't need the index so it is easier.  But try doing this using an indexed for loop.  It can be done, but not as easily.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(
                List.of(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 10));
Iterator<Integer> it = list.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
   // if even, remove it.
   if (it.next() % 2 == 0) {
      it.remove();
   }
}
System.out.println(list);
```

Prints

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Using an `interator` allows you to modify lists that might otherwise trigger a concurrent modification exception.

Also, assume you had a class implementation that generated primes or fibonacci numbers.  You could do this to grab them individually.

```
Fibonacci fib = new Fibonacci(0, 1, 10);
for (long i : fib) {
    System.out.print(i + " ");
}
```

Prints

```
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34
```

The Fibonacci class

```
class Fibonacci implements Iterable<Long> {
    public long start;
    public long next;
    public long count;
    
    public Fibonacci(int start, int next, int count) {
        this.start = start;
        this.next = next;
        this.count = count;
    }
    
    private class MyIterator implements Iterator<Long> {
        int n = 0;
        
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return n < count;
        }
        
        public Long next() {
            n++;
            long ret = start;
            start = start + next;
            next = ret;
            return ret;
        }
    }
    
    public Iterator<Long> iterator() {
        return new MyIterator();
    }
}
```

By implementing `Iterable` in the class I can use the `foreach` construct to get elements of the class.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have benefit of using it directly. But the iterator is used by for example the forEach.

Comment: i thought the question was "why use an iterator?". So what I wrote is an answer to that. Not a comment. Maybe I misunderstood the question then.

Answer (score 0):

Just to loop through it you don't need an iterator, a for loop will suffice. If you need to modify the list then you need it to avoid ConcurrentModificationException.